Is there a way to open a batch file at a certain line using a command prompt window
Im testing a batch file that Im still in the process of making and I want to open it at line 6 instead of line 1 since ive already run that part of the code. it takes a couple of minutes to run it since im using ffmpeg.
this is the first area of the code
@Echo off
set /p IPath=Enter the Path of the file you wish to remux from (use "Copy as path" option and keep  the Quotations): 
set /P M=what is the first letter of the path of your new file?(do not include the semicolon(:))
set /p NewPath=Enter the Path you wish to remux to (must be path minus the directory BUT do not use  Quotations for this)(I also recommend using a single folder to hold the files while remuxing them before sending them  to their separate folders):
ffmpeg -i %IPath%  -c copy -map 0 "%M%:\%NewPath%"
goto :Premiere &:: This command takes inputs from the previous lines and sets up to remux files

:Premiere &:: this command line starts the preferred editor and waits 30 seconds to allow it to start
set /p EDITOR=Enter the .exe file for your prefered editor should look like: 'Adobe Premiere Pro.exe':
start "" "%EDITOR%"
echo Starting Process. . . Please Wait
timeout /t 30
tasklist | find /I "%EDITOR%" &:: The next couple of lines test for the editor to see if it opened or not
if errorlevel 1 (
     echo could not start process 
     goto :FailEditor
) Else (
     echo Process completed, next question--->
     goto :choice
)

so instead of starting at line 1 i would like to start at line 6 to bypass the longest section of the code.
Im thinking its something along the lines of
Start M:\REMUX.bat at line 6
however AT is a command to tell a time to start the batch file so im not sure

Can you not, for now, just prepend the unwanted lines with remarks, (Rem), or invalid labels, (::)?

I mean yes, I can but this is also for the future as well just for testing code or giving direction to others who want to use it as well

also if you can find any faults in this code please let me know

First of all, in BATch files there are not "lines", there are :labels. You can start your batch file with if "%1" neq "" goto %1. After that, use Start M:\REMUX.bat to start it from the beginning, or use Start M:\REMUX.bat Premiere to start it from :Premiere label. You can also use if /I "%1 %2" equ "at label" goto %3 and then use Start M:\REMUX.bat at label Premiere ;)

I am new to using and creating batch files so i didnt know that there werent "lines" as i am using Visual studio code for it. but that asnwers my question

You would need to specify HOW the code is supposed to detect that the lines be skipped. Since you have omitted a setlocal command, IPath, M and NewPath would remain set at the end of the process, assuming that you are running this code in a cmd window, not from a "shortcut". Your code shows no use of a parameter - could you supply a parameter (like /quick for instance) and simply scan %* for the presence of that parameter to skip over the [un]required code?

Yes, of course, the text file where you write the prompts does have lines. No matter the editor you use. But the executing code does not work with "lines" as @Aacini stated. To run the script in different ways, I propose you do as @Aacini wrote but create a second BAT file (e.g. "REMUX_premiere.bar") and in there you write CALL REMUX.bat Premiere. Now, your user can choose if he wants to run the full script or from the label :Premiere.

I forgot: You need to end your main script with EXIT /B 0 for this to work. And of course the two files should be kept together. Otherwise, you need to specify the path to the main script in the second script.  For improvements: take a look at query process to check if your editor is running. See example here

Why are there no line numbers in the code listings?. Please remove the line numbers
